# How many cardboard digits do I need?

Tags: code-golf, number

I need to prepare digits made of cardboard to display some number ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWidM.jpg)). I don't know beforehand which number I should display - the only thing I know is that it's not greater than `n`.

How many cardboard digits should I prepare?

Example: `n = 50`

To display any number in the range 0...50, I need the following digits:

1. A zero, for displaying the number 0, or any other round number
2. Two copies of digits 1, 2, 3 and 4, for displaying the corresponding numbers
3. One copy of digits 5, 6, 7 and 8, for the case they appear as least significant digit in the number
4. The digit 9 is never needed, because I can use the inverted digit 6 instead

Total: 13 digits

Test cases (each line is a test case in the format "input; output")

```
0 1
1 2
9 9
11 10
50 13
99 17
100 18
135 19
531 22
1000 27
8192 34
32767 38
```

Comment: Can any other digit be rotated besides 6/9?

Comment: No (see example)

Comment: So two 1's can't be overlaid to make a 7 then

Comment: ... and two zeros cannot make a 8. That would be ugly.

Comment: Probably an awkward question, but as these are 'cardboard' digits, can they be double-sided printed to save on the total required? In the example, you would never need 6 and 0 together, for instance.

Comment: @Weckar He probably wants to cut them out of cardboard, not print them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
‘ḶDœ|/ḟ9L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4oCY4bi2RMWTfC/huJ85TP///zMyNzY3)

### How it works

```
‘ḶDœ|/ḟ9L
‘Ḷ         [0,1,...,n]
  D        convert each to list of its digits
   œ|/     fold by multiset union
      ḟ9   remove 9
        L  length
```

Comment: Too fast >.< I swear, you have a Jelly answer for every known challenge in the universe and you just have a bot to post them right after the challenge. :P Nice answer.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I think the bot extracts testcases from the challenge and tries every possible jelly program using a supercomputer.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino You know the feeling...especially if your solution is `0rDŒr€ẎQṪÞẎḟ9ĠẎL`.

Comment: I doubted the validity of ḟ9 part for a moment, then I realised 6 < 9 so number of 6s can't be less than the total possible number of 6s and 9s combined in each combination.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda n:9*len(`n`)-9+(n*9+8)/10**len(`n`)+(n<10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrBDoIwEETP7FfssQXUbhuEEvsnJlIiBBKoDWKIX4@rB@cwk7x58b0Oj6D33l33yc/t3WOobTp1QTShkQebiZDarJInUukfM7yQkvs2jFOHVEPi89bNPooxrPnit9sY4msV8viM08grIVlcLzxvXNhBn@OSY8vtXLsrJCDUoNGARQukvkVICgr@GFqkEsgUSBYKw65mSSnUJRhdnks0FVS/YGE@)

A clumsy arithmetical formula. Assume that `n` fits within an `int` so that an `L` isn't appended.

Thanks to Neil for saving 5 bytes by pointing out that 9's being unused could be handled by doing `n*9+8` instead of `n*9+9`, so that, say, `999*9+8=8999` doesn't roll over to 9000.

Comment: @ovs That doesn't quite work, it's not enough to know the first digit. For example `33333` requires five 3's but `22222` requires only four. `n*9`[0] 
  is tempting, but fails for numbers starting with `1` and less that `111..`.

Comment: By my calculations (see my Batch answer) you can probably use ``(n*9+8)/10**len(`n`)`` to avoid using `min`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>117</s> <s>114</s> <s>108</s> <s>95</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> <s>84</s> <s>82</s> 63 bytes

*6 bytes saved thanks to Laikoni*

*<s>1</s> <s>4</s> 6 bytes saved thanks to nimi*

```hs
g x=sum[maximum[sum[1|u<-show y,d==u]|y<-[0..x]]|d<-['0'..'8']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P12hwra4NDc6N7EiMxdIg9iGNaU2usUZ@eUKlToptralsTWVNrrRBnp6FbGxNSlAprqBup6euoV6bOz/3MTMPCsrT38NTS4Q07agKDOvRCVdwdDI0vg/AA)

Comment: 1.) `maximum[a,b]` is the same as `max a b`. 2.) List comprehensions are often shorter than `filter`: `max d$sum[1|x<-show a,x==b]`

Comment: You can replace `g` with a pointfree function literal: `sum.(#[-9..])`.

Comment: @nimi I don't know what a pointfree function literal is, but I think I see what you are suggesting.  Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ... and `length[x|x<-...]` is `sum[1|x<-...]`.

Comment: Functions can be unnamed, so no need for the `g=` (but maybe you want to include it in the TIO version).

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
Tr@Delete[Max~MapThread~DigitCount@Range[0,#],9]&
```

Comment: nice! Is this based on my answer?

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 67 bytes

```
@if %1 geq 10%2 %0 %1 0%2 -~%3
@cmd/cset/a(%1*9+8)/10%2+9*%30+!%30
```

In the standard formulation of this problem, you need separate `6` and `9` digits, but you're not required to display `0`. As the maximum value `n` required increases, the number of required numerals increases every time you reach a repdigit (because you don't quite have enough of that numeral) and every time you reach a power of `10` (when you need an extra zero). In total each power of `10` needs `10` more numerals than the previous one, which can be caluclated as `floor(log10(n))*10`. For values of `n` between powers of 10, the number of intermediate repdigits can then be calculated as `floor(n/((10**floor(log10(n))*10-1)/9))` or alternatively `floor(n*9/(10**floor(log10(n))*10-1))`.

I calculate `floor(log10(n))` by means of the loop on the first line. Each time, `%2` gains an extra `0` and `%3` gains an extra `-~`. This means that `10%2` is `10*10**floor(log10(n))` and `%30` is `floor(log10(n))`.

The duplication of `6` and `9` has two effects: firstly, there are only `9` numerals required for each power of `10`, and secondly the repdigit detection needs to ignore the `9` repdigits. Fortunately as they are one less than a power of 10 this can be achieved by tweaking the formula to result in `floor((n*9+8)/(10**floor(log10(n))*10))`.

Dealing with the zero is reasonably simple: this just requires an extra numeral when `n<10`, i.e. `floor(log10(n))==0`.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>60</s> 53 bytes

```
f=(n,i=9)=>n>(i%9+1+"e"+(i/9|0))/9-1?1+f(n,-~i):n>9^1
```

A sort of hacky recursive solution. This generates the numbers which require adding a digit:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 100, 111, 222, ...
```

and then counts how many are less than the input. By a happy miracle, removing the digit `9` actually *removes* several bytes from the function, because the sequence can then be generated like so (assuming integer division):

```
1e1 / 9 = 1, 2e1 / 9 = 2, ..., 8e1 / 9 = 8, 9e1 / 9 = 10, 1e2 / 9 = 11, 2e2 / 9 = 22, ...
```

We do have to take into account the fact that numbers under 10 still require the zero, but this is as simple as adding `n > 9 ? 0 : 1` to the result.

#### Test cases

```js
let f=(n,i=9)=>n>(i%9+1+"e"+(i/9|0))/9-1?1+f(n,i+1):n>9^1;

[0, 1, 9, 11, 50, 99, 100, 135, 531, 1000, 8192, 32767].map(n => console.log(f(n)));
```

Comment: `n>9^1` can probably be `n<10`

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Well, that gives `true` for input `0`, so I'm a little hesitant to do that.

Comment: `0>9` is false, `false^1` is 1...?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Yes, I'm saying I'm hesitant to *output* the boolean `true` in place of the number `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 83 bytes

```
v=DigitCount;s=v@0;(Table[s[[i]]=v[j][[i]]~Max~s[[i]],{i,10},{j,#}];s[[9]]=0;Tr@s)&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(max(str(j).count(str(i))for j in range(n+1))for i in range(9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyM3sUKjuKRII0tTLzm/NK8EzMnU1EzLL1LIUsjMUyhKzEtP1cjTNoSIZSLELDU1/xcUZQL1pGkYaGpywdiGSGxLZHFkCVNkHZYoyoxNkdUZI@syNDBA1mdsZG5mDnQFAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 60 bytes

```php
<?=count(preg_grep('#^100+$|^([0-8])\1*$#',range(0,$argn)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkbGRuZq5kzWVvBxS3Tc4vzSvRKChKTY9PL0ot0FBXjjM0MNBWqYnTiDbQtYjVjDHUUlFW1ylKzEtP1TDQARuiqalp/f8/AA)