# How many times should I press this?

Tags: code-golf, string, number, keyboard

We are all used to the old-school telephone keypad, right? For reference, here is what it looks like:

[image: Telephone Keybad]

---

Given a String consisting only of **lowercase ASCII letters and single spaces**, your task is to return the number of taps one should make in order to type down the full String with a telephone keypad as the one above.

For those who are unfamiliar with this, here's how it works:

- The key with the digit `2`, for example, also has the string `abc` written down on it. In order to type `a`, you must press this key once, for `b` you must press twice and for `c` you must press thrice.
- For consecutive letters that are on the same key, you must wait 1 second before pressing again. So, if you want to type `cb`, you must press 3 times for `c`, wait a second and then press twice for `b`, so still 5 taps.
- The same applies for all other keys, except for a *single* space, which only requires 1 press. Also note that the keys `7` and `9` have four letters on them. The same algorithm is applied, the only difference being the number of letters. The strings corresponding to each key can be found in the image above (but lowercase), or in the following list, that contains all the characters you might receive:

  ```
  "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz", " "
  ```

## Test Cases

```
Input  ->  Output  (Explanation)

"" -> 0                   (nothing should be tapped)
"water" -> 8              ("w,a,t" each require 1 tap (on keys 9, 2 and 8), "e" requires 2 taps (on key 3), "r" requires 3 taps (on key 7), 1+1+1+2+3 = 8)
"soap"  -> 9              (4+3+1+1)
"candela" -> 13           (3+1+2+1+2+3+1)
"code golf" -> 20         (3+3+1+2+1(for the space)+1+3+3+3)
"king of the hill" -> 33  (2+3+2+1+1+3+3+1+1+2+2+1+2+3+3+3)
```

## Specs

- Standard I/O rules and Default Loopholes apply.
- You may only take input in your language's native String type. Output can either be an integer or a string representation of that integer.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer *in every language* wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24696/optimizing-the-telephone-keypad), [Inspired by this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/128202/how-many-cardboard-digits-do-i-need)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61545/58974). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/32817/58974).

Comment: I think this would be a more interesting question if you did 1 tap per second, and had to wait 1 second, and counted *seconds* instead of taps.

Comment: @Yakk That would be far too complicated

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Are you sure though? I have seen the code-wizards here do impossible stuff in less space than a tweet.

Comment: @J_F_B_M That wouldn't be very hard, but it is too complicated for the purpose of this challenge, at least.

Comment: Thrice, word is thrice. Once, twice, thrice. As a non-English speaker I saw our common struggle there :)

Comment: @EgeBayrak Happy now?

Comment: Can we take all uppercase if that makes the code shorter?

Comment: @Adám No, sorry. I don't want to create confusion with old answers that might become shorter too.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6) <s>77</s> <s>66</s> <s>64</s> 60 bytes

(Saved some bytes thanks to @Johan Karlsson and @Arnauld).

```
s=>[...s].map(l=>s=~~s+2+'behknquxcfilorvysz'.search(l)/8)|s
```

```js
f=

s=>[...s].map(l=>s=~~s+2+'behknquxcfilorvysz'.search(l)/8)|s

console.log(f(''));                 //0
console.log(f('water'));            //8
console.log(f('soap'));             //9
console.log(f('candela'));          //13
console.log(f('code golf'));        //20
console.log(f('king of the hill')); //33
```

Comment: `(s,t=0)=>[...s].map(l=>t+=(1+'behknquxcfilorvysz'.indexOf(l)/8|0)+1)&&t` for 71 bytes

Comment: Thanks, @JohanKarlsson, I figured the same thing while in the shower!  Found another optimization to shave off 5 more bytes.

Comment: I found a purely arithmetical solution for 71 bytes: `f=s=>[...s].map(c=>t+=((c=parseInt(0+c,36))>23?c+3:c&&~-c%3)%7%4+1,t=0)|t`.

Comment: @Neil, while that may not be shorter, it is certainly cleverer.

Comment: @Neil You should post it.

Comment: `s=>[...s].map(l=>s=~~s+2+'behknquxcfilorvysz'.search(l)/8)|s` should save 4 bytes, decimal parts being truncated by `~~s` on each iteration and ultimately by `|s`.

Comment: Sweet, I'll study that and update later, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>29</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
ð¢svA•22ā₂•S£ð«øðδKy.åƶOO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8IZDi4rLHB81LDIyOtL4qKkJyAo@tBgovPrwjsMbzm3xrtQ7vPTYNn////@zM/PSFfLTFEoyUhUyMnNyAA)

**Explanation**

```
ð¢                         # count spaces in input
  sv                       # for each char y in input
    A                      # push the lowercase alphabet
     •22ā₂•S               # push the base-10 digit list [3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4]
            £              # split the alphabet into pieces of these sizes
             ð«            # append a space to each
               ø           # transpose
                ðδK        # deep remove spaces
                   y.å     # check y for membership of each
                      ƶ    # lift each by their index in the list
                       O   # sum the list
                        O  # sum the stack
```

Comment: Sorry, but for an empty input this gives 10. It is fine elsewhere

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: The empty string gives no output, but it's still wrong. Thanks for notifying, I'll fix it.

Comment: It gives 10 on TIO.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Yeah you have to explicitly give the empty string. No input is not the same as an empty string. It is a bit confusing I know. Fixed now though :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: Empty string input is given like [this](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Ab1RKsyx0cNi4yMjjQ@amoCsoIPLT684dDqwzsObzi3xdurUu/w0mPbajX9/f//VwIDAA)

Comment: @Emigna Won't just `\n` suffice?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: A literal line break would work as well yes :)

Comment: Ooh, didn't know `£` would behave like that...it's supposed to do `a[:b]` right?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Yep. But if b is a list instead of an int it repeatedly does `a[:b]` on the remainder of `a` for each element in `b` basically.

Comment: `ƵÜbS3+` pushes `[3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4]` but reversed.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: I also had `ƵxbRS3+` as well as `•M†–•5в`, but unfortunately they are all the same size :(

Comment: `•Cç•3вÌ` also works.

Comment: -1 by using `ðм` instead of `ðδK`. Probably wasn't available yet at time of posting (and currently it also doesn't work in the TIO since the items are wrapped in inner lists, so a third `O` would be necessary..)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

Uses the same algorithm as [@RickHitchcock's Javascript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128827/64121)

```python
lambda x:sum('behknquxcfilorvysz'.find(c)/8+2for c in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1LDsIgFIXhuau4MyBWTToyTXQj6oDyEFLKRUq1tenaUXR0vjP6w5wM@jrr0zU73reSw9QMY09Jq0znH@MktHUYn/PwJnttvaSCHY7bWmMEAdbDxHJxUkMq90JIBeTFk4oFA/JQVnAvleM/olRwR6fL6ay/A2pIRoGxzpFbswEI0foEZFlhd4Zl/YYx9jzRqEKkpcQq0H@w/AE)

Comment: Interesting solution. How does it work for spaces, I don't get it >.<?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder for anything not in the string `'...'.find(c)` returns `-1`. By adding 2 we get one keypress.

Comment: I knew it returned `-1`, but didn't realize you have a `+2` after the boilerplate... Anyway, the shortest Python solution by far.

Comment: Oml, I happened to make the exact same solution after slowly golfing my program down, until I realized you posted it :( Nice job for finding this solution as well :)

Answer (score 5):

## Dyalog APL, 37 bytes

```
+/⌈9÷⍨'adgjmptw behknqux~cfilorvy~'⍳⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYs7DsIwEET7nMJdChRRc5yNfzFZvCY2hFCkJQW@AjU9BQfgJr6IEUiYqea90YDDRkyApBuO4L3hOS0XlVfrdF02r2eK9xqE3u5cGFkru97uD6eZK4M0HKe5TvGR4u3zyewbVVW/MkKQQyFP4ApwsEIiFG5BSzz/ZxKSaUJVTG@sZqRY6CTrDOIb)

**How?**

Get the `⍳`ndex of every char of the input in the string `'adgjmptw behknqux~cfilorvy~'` (`s` and `z` will default to 28), divide by 9, round up and sum.

Comment: You can use `'adgjmptw ' 'behknqux' 'cfilorvy' 'sz'` to save some bytes

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jcs7DsIwEEXRnlW4c2FFCMGGBv/JYJs4EMJnSrpI7AWxIW8kRKZ5Oq@4kLBRI2C0jUTI2ct5NuX1vov1RuweW8FhL0lpQ9Z5OrRIxxApnbrcny80XMcb42X6lOn7XELG@WqZAXrdVeUIqUJCUBrh76g0sxFNfa0PlkXDeqeZ84j8Bw)

Comment: @LeakyNun onice

Comment: You can drop the space in the string

Comment: @Uriel wait, you don't need to count `f←` so it is 47 bytes

Comment: @LeakyNun yup. and 46

Comment: Save a byte by [converting to tradfn](https://tio.run/##RYs7DsIwEET7nMJdChRRc5yNfzFZvCY2hFCkJQW@AjU9BQfgJr6IEUiYqea90YDDRkyApBuO4L3hOS0XlVfrdF02r2eK9xqE3u5cGFkru97uD6eZK4M0HKe5TvGR4u3zyewbVVW/MkKQQyFP4ApwsEIiFG5BSzz/ZxKSaUJVTG@sZqRY6CTrDOIb "APL (Dyalog Classic) – Try It Online").

Comment: @Adám but trains looks so much better! ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>69</s> <s>67</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder.

1 byte thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista.

```python
lambda x:sum((ord(i)+~(i>"s"))%3+3*(i in"sz")+(i>" ")for i in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VclNCsMgEEDhfU8xDBRm6tJdITlJNpbEOsRoUEt@Fr26rZtCl@9761FcDLrabqjeLI/RwH7Pr4UoppGE1Zukx4zMV630jQQkYD6RVXNAtjFBQ9i5rklCIUvN@fKrzZQp/cks4QnRQnETOPH@O@sH)

Comment: Save one byte by replacing `i==" "` with `i<"a"`, because you only receive letters and spaces

Comment: 61 minutes...too late!

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

```js
f=
s=>[...s].map(c=>t+=((c=parseInt(0+c,36))>23?c+3:c&&~-c%3)%7%4+1,t=0)|t
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Look no letter tables! I didn't quite understand @LeakyNun's formula so I came up with my own.

Comment: Pure arithmetic :)

Comment: What does `s=>[...s]` do why not just `s=>s.map()...`

Comment: @EvanCarroll `s` is a string, so you can't `map` it directly. `...s` iterates over `s`, while `[...s]` converts the iteration into an array, effectively splitting `s` into an array of characters.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <del>211</del> 196 bytes

First submission here...looks quite lengthy and I see that this is not an efficient approach, but at least it works :)

```
f(char*n){char*k=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";int t[]={0,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4};int l=0,s,j,i;while(*n){i=0;while(k[i]){if(k[i]==*n){s=0;for(j=0;s<i-t[j];s+=t[j++]);*n++;l+=(!i?1:i-s);}i++;}}return l;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
int f(char *n){
  char *k=" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  int t[]={0,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4};
  int l=0,s,j,i;
  while(*n){                          // loop through input characters
    i=0;
    while(k[i]){
      if(k[i]==*n){                   // find matching char in k
        s=0;
        for(j=0;s<i-t[j];s+=t[j++]);  // sum up the "key sizes" up to the key found
        *n++;
        l+=(!i?1:i-s);                // key presses are i-s except for space (1)
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
  return l;
}
```

Comment: `*(k+i)` can be `k[i]`.

Comment: You can cut the space after an `*` (e.g. `char*n`), and add your declarations to your empty `for` statement (instead of `int s=0,j=0;(for(;` you'd have `for(int s=0,k=0;`) and instead of `i==0` use `!i`

Comment: Thank you for those hints. I couldn't put `s` into the for loop because I use it later on, but I put the `int` declarations together and used assignemts where I needed them.

Comment: Yay a fellow C golfer! Anyways, some pointers: for loops are strictly better than while loops in almost all situation - take advantage of the free semicolons, particularly in the iteration expression. Use commas instead of semicolons in most places, this allows you to get away with not having curly braces in most places. There are other optimizations but they are more reliant on which version of C you compile to.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell - <s>74</s> <s>71</s> 62 bytes

*Edit: removed 3 bytes by using a list comprehension instead of filter*

*Edit: Save 9 bytes thanks to Siracusa, Laikoni and Zgarb!*

```
f=sum.(>>= \x->1:[1|y<-"bcceffhiikllnooqrrsssuvvxyyzzz",y==x])
```

### Usage

```
λ> f "candela"
13
λ>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZckxDsIgFADQ3VP8EAdNbJOuRnoRdcAChfSXX6GtQLw77rK@Z0SYFGIpmodtbk99z@ERm7673rtvujXsNQxKa2PthOiI3t6HELZ9jynlnNklcR6f5zIL64CDpAPA4q1boQUNR2DsHz5iVb7SQGKpcBBOKhS1k1QwEupqJutGIA2rUWAsIis/)

Comment: What is the purpose of the duplicate letters?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It's used to count the taps, I will add an explanation.

Comment: You can save one byte by rewriting `f` to `f=length.(=<<)(\x->x:[y|y<-l,y==x])`, where `(=<<)` is `concatMap` here.

Comment: And another one with going back to `filter`: `f=length.(=<<)(\x->x:filter(==x)l)`

Comment: As you use `l` only once, it can be inlined.

Comment: Use a single sum instead of sum of lengths: `sum.(>>= \x->1:[1|y<-l,y==x])`. Also, as Laikoni said, inline `l`.

Comment: Haven't gotten to the chapters on Monoids/Functors/Applicatives, so I am afraid I have never used `=<<`. I tried to do as you suggested, but was unable to get it working. @siracusa

Comment: Oh, what was the problem?

Comment: @siracusa Oh! I thought you were giving me partial code, so I tried to add stuff to what I thought would work. Now that I tried what you posted, I was able to get it to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
Øaḟ⁾sz©;⁶s3Z®ṭċ@€€⁸×"J$ẎS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjMSHO@Y/atxXXHVopfWjxm3FxlGH1j3cufZIt8OjpjUg1Ljj8HQlL5WHu/qC////n5yYl5KakwgA)

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, <s>82</s> 76 bytes

```
#(apply +(for[c %](+(count(filter #{c}"bcceffhiikllnooqrrsssuvvxyyzzz"))1)))
```

Oh it is simpler to just `filter` and `count` than use `frequencies`. Original:

```
#(apply +(count %)(for[c %](get(frequencies"bcceffhiikllnooqrrsssuvvxyyzzz")c 0)))
```

The string encodes how many times more than just once you need to press the key for a given character :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 91 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(j.find(i)+1for j in' !abc!def!ghi!jkl!mno!pqrs!tuv!wxyz'.split('!')for i in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBDsIgEADvvmK3FyAmTYw3E3/ihbZQllJAoLb181gvJh5nJhP3YoK/Vn1/VCfnbpCw3fIyc9tq8gMncb7okMACeQYoux4HpXE0hHZyOPuA8ZkyluWF67a/WZujo8IZMvH96PhgEzUm8oVr3kAjxOlHqywq/ZmJ/AhBQzEKDDl3xPoB)

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>46</s> 36 bytes

*Thanks to CalculatorFeline for saving 6 bytes.*

```
s|z
,c
[cfilorvy]
,b
[behknqux]
,,
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdBDoMgEAXQ/T8FGxMXpNfwEMTEEQchTpgWaWsb746@3StcU6bW9cPU9vMP6@F8SKLl8xthZ7iZ45Zf7@OexaM1fKlywa70hKe8sBC8LmxWlYAt5dVoMDWyiUnkAg)

Answer (score 2):

### Java, <s>95</s> 73 bytes

```
a->a.chars().map(b->1+(b<64?0:b+(Math.abs(b-115)<4?4:5))%(3+b/112)).sum()
```

Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for making the function a lambda expression (where `a` is of type `String`). 95 bytes became 73 bytes!

A lambda expression sums up the press count of each character using `map()`. `map()` converts each character (ASCII in lower case range is 97-122) in the stream to the appropriate value (looks like simple saw wave, but taking into account both 4 cycles is annoying) using this math: `1+(b<64?0:b+(Math.abs(b-115)<4?4:5))%(3+b/112)`. [Here's](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/86ii5wwvmg) a desmos graph of that model.

Comment: The loophole list says not to post code snippets even though it looks like everyone so far has done that. Either way, my full program is **130 bytes**. Here it is: `interface Z{static void main(String a){System.out.print(a.chars().map(b->1+(b<64?0:b+(Math.abs(b-115)<4?4:5))%(3+b/112)).sum());}}`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You're indeed right that snippets aren't allowed, but the default is program or **function**. And with Java 8 you can use lambdas. So in this case `a->{return a.chars().map(b->1+(b<64?0:b+(Math.abs(b-115)<4?4:5))%(3+b/112)).sum();}` is allowed. And since it's a single return statement, `a->a.chars().map(b->1+(b<64?0:b+(Math.abs(b-115)<4?4:5))%(3+b/112)).sum()` (**73 bytes**) would be your answer. Also, here is a [TryItOnline-link](https://tinyurl.com/ybpcrj5s) of your answer you might want to add to your answer. Again: welcome, and nice answer. +1 from me.

Comment: Some things to note about lambdas. You don't have to count `f=` nor the leading semi-colon `;`. And you also don't have to add the type of the parameter as long as you mention what the type is (so instead of `(String a)->` you can use `a->` and mention that input `a` is a `String` in your answer). Oh, and [Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read, in case you haven't yet.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

Probably sub-optimal, as this is my first golf ever in Python.

```python
lambda x:sum((ord(i)-8)%3.15//1+3*(i>'y')+(i>' ')for i in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VclBCsIwEIXhvaeYjSRj0VKCIIKexE00STOYZkIasT191I2Q1eP/XlqL56iqu9xq0NPdaFjO82uSkrORhPsTbtVhOPb90KmdpKtYBXa/BYGOMxBQhAVryhSLdFIIxM0/3rrY3MjMOjXw0NHYoFtjY2Hk4Bp9UhyBHRRvwVMI37N@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>100</s> 90 bytes

```
a:qb:["abc""def""ghi""jkl""mno""pqrs""tuv""wxyz"s]Fc,#a{Fd,#b{e:((bd)@?(ac))e<4?i+:e+1x}}i
```

Check each character of the input for a match in each element of b. The index of that match plus 1 gets added to the total.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDoIwFAXQrTSXSRuYmDhqTHDEJgyDfh70SYUiqChh7fWcxClno2erbzDWAZ46oA8M3IcIPMYJSPNzAdbXG/hs3x@WtnFVYfbGV4XdSUtpvbrW0jil6HKuudRUnrbj4JwHHnsxdWINJALH@Ac)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 83 bytes

```
c=Characters;Tr[Tr@Mod[c@"bc1def1ghi1jkl1mno1pqrstuv1wxyz "~Position~#,4]+1&/@c@#]&
```

Comment: It seems to be generally accepted that Mathematica answers are allowed to use lists of characters for string variables, such as the input to this function. (Also is there an `a` missing at the start of `"bc1..."`?)

Comment: this is code golf.this gives the right result without a."Tr " does the job

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 94 bytes

```
[_l;||_SA,a,1|p=p-(instr(@sz`,B)>0)-(instr(@cfilorvy`+C,B)>0)-(instr(@behknqux`+C+D,B)>0)+1}?p
```

### Explanation

```
[    |      FOR a = 1 TO
 _l |         the length of
   ;            the input string (A$)
_SA,a,1|    Take the a'th char of A$ and assign it to B$
p=p         p is our tap-counter, and in each iteration it gets increased by the code below
            which consist of this pattern:
                instr(@xyz`,B)>0    where 
                - instr tests if arg 2 is in arg 1 (it either returns 0 or X where X is the index of a2 in a1)
                - @...` defines the letters we want to test as arg1
                - B is the current letter to count the taps for
            Each of these blocks adds 1 tap to the counter, and each block has the letters of its level
            (4-taps, 3-taps or 2-taps) and the level 'above' it.
    -(instr(@sz`,B)>0)              <-- letters that require 4 taps
    -(instr(@cfilorvy`+C,B)>0)      <-- 3 or 4 taps
    -(instr(@behknqux`+C+D,B)>0)    <-- 2, 3,or 4 taps
    +1                              <-- and always a 1-tap
}           NEXT
?p          PRINT the number of taps
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <del>69</del>  68 bytes

```bash
bc<<<`fold -1|tr "\n "adgjmptwbehknquxcfilorvysz +[1*9][2*8][3*8]44`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PynZxsYmIS0/J0VB17CmpEhBKSZPQSkxJT0rt6CkPCk1IzuvsLQiOS0zJ7@orLK4SkE72lDLMjbaSMsiNtoYSJiYJPz/n5yfkqqQnp@T9v8/AA)

Folds one char per line, transliterates each newline with `+`, each space with     `1` and each letter with the corresponding number of pushes. bc does the sum.

Comment: on your machine you may need `bc <(fold -1|tr "\n "adgjmptwbehknquxcfilorvysz +[1*9][2*8][3*8]44;echo 0)`

Answer (score 1):

### C, <strike>92</strike> 88 bytes

```
c,n;f(char*s){n=0;while(c=*s++)n+=(c=='s')+3*(c>'y')+1+(c+1+(c<'s'))%3-(c<33);return n;}
```

Comment: you may use `s=n` to replace `return n`, and combine `s++;` with `c=*s`. It could be 9 bytes shorter.

Comment: @KeyuGan `s=n` wouldn't work, since `s` is a local.  And `*s=n` wouldn't work since there are only `CHAR_BIT` bits in `*s`, which wouldn't be enough for some messages.  But you're right about the `s++`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 75 <del>77</del> bytes

```c
n,b;f(char*a){for(n=0;b=*a++;)n+=b<'s'?--b%3+(b>31):""[b-'s'];a=n;}
```

The unprintable string `""` is a table of `04 01 02 03 01 02 03 04`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYpBDoIwFESjsuIUTRNCC5Jg2FnRg6iL39ICEX9JwbggnB27ciVOZjGZ91RWK7UsuJfCMNWAS4BPxjqGZS5kmUCaCo5pKU/xEF@yTEZFyuS5OPAjDTbbnW9ArzLz9C6gRDEvLY7kCS0yHk4h8emdvwyjUXVDuveDci5@kzeM2q3jwUK/ThVgpTv4I9hKk9p2Zl15tFgTa8jYaNK0Xfc1nR5fDkkuwjlcPg)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 bytes

```apl
{+/(3×⍵∊'sz'),1+3|¯1+⍵⍳⍨819⌶⎕A~'SZ'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhGptfQ3jw9Mf9W591NGlXlylrqljqG1cc2i9oTZIrHfzo94VFoaWj3q2Peqb6linHhylXgvUqaCuzgUkyhNLUovArOL8xAIwIzkxLyU1JxHMTkpMT82pggjnp6QqpOfnpIF52Zl56Qr5aQolGakKGZk5OeoA)

Finds the mod-3 indices in the alphabet without *S* and *Z*. Since space, *S*, and *Z* are not found, they "have" index 25 (one more than the max index), which is good for space. Then we just need to add 3 for each *S* or *Z*.

`{` anonymous function where the argument is represented by *⍵*:

`⎕A~'SZ'` the uppercase **A**lphabet, except for *S* and *Z*

`819⌶` lowercase

`⍵⍳⍨` the **ɩ**ndices of the argument in that

`¯1+` add negative one

`3|` mod-3

`1+` add one (this converts all 0-mods to 3)

`(`…`),` prepend:

`⍵∊'sz'` Boolean where the argument is either *s* or *z*

`3×` multiply by 3

`+/` sum